# Riddle question

Tags: translation, meaning, ambiguity, puns

I would appreciate some help in solving this riddle.

There is a sign that says "どくぞごじゆうにおとりくだちい" in front of candy samples at the candy shop. It means "Please feel free to take (one)." However, you saw one passer-by taking as many as fifty-two of them. Why do you think that this person did so?

Thanks!

Comment: Aside of a possible typo on どくぞ→どうぞ, another typo is くだちい→ください

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the beginning is 「どうぞ」 and not 「どくぞ」, then it is quite simple.

The sign says **ごじゆうに** おとりください.  The store owner's *intended* meaning is ご[自由]{じ・ゆう}に, which means "freely" or "feel free to".  However, if the sign was written only in hiragana, the person might have mistook it for ごじ**ゅ**うに (notice the small-sized ゅ instead of the larger ゆ).  In this case, as we know, ごじゅうに means "52".